# SAP BODS error Correlation name '' not found

Tags: jobs, sap-data-services

I am working with SAP Data Services at the moment. I need to load a load procedure from the SQL file. And I'm getting this error:

> SQL submitted to ODBC data source  resulted in error <[Sybase][ODBC Driver][Sybase IQ]Correlation name 't_table' not
> found>. The SQL submitted is <call LB.load_procedure('I:\SybaseLoadDEV', 2017, 3)>.

Had someone the same error? I spent 2 days already and can't find any solution!
Thanks
P.S.: all aliases are OK

Answer (score 0):

Function call wasn't correct. Now it running correct